# Why RSA is said to be faster than ElGamal Encryption?

Tags: encryption, rsa, elgamal

For RSA, every block of plaintext needs to be exponentiated by the private key: p^e (mod n)
For ElGamal, every block of plaintext is multiplied by the secret key s*m (mod n)

So I thought ElGamal would be faster than RSA for encryption.  However most online articles say RSA is faster than ElGamal, why is that?

Comment: This is not a programming question. You could ask on the [crypto site](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) but please first look at Q/A's such as [these](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1677/when-to-use-rsa-and-when-elgamal-asymmetric-encryption).

Comment: A bicycle is faster than a F-16 in some cases. Also, I don't think you understand ElGamal.

Comment: You shouldn’t use RSA on blocked plaintext. Just for small messages, like an AES key.